# ¿Como esconder el controlador en la url con codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

No doy con la manera de esconder el nombre de controlador y su función, en la url de mi web.

Tengo varios `controladores`, uno de ellos es `blog`, el cual es el `controlador por defecto` establecido en el fichero `routes.php`.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'blog';
```

He estado probando varias cosas, entre ellas, establecer el siguiente codigo en el fichero `routes.php`.

```
$route['entradas'] = 'blog/entradas';
```

Pero no consigo que funcione y es algo que me trae de cabeza, ya que actualmente estoy aprendiendo codeigniter, si alguien puede iluminarme se lo agradecería

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede definir una ruta personalizada en **config/routes.php**, por ejemplo:

```
$route['entradas'] = 'blog/entradas';

Entonces, http://example.com/entradas
Va a http://example.com/blog/entradas
```

En otras palabras mas explicado:

Existe un archivo donde podemos generar todo tipo de reglas para conseguir un enrutado de URIs distinto del predeterminado. Ese archivo lo podemos encontrar en el directorio de los archivos de configuración:

```
system/application/config/routes.php
```

Allí podremos definir un **array** llamado **$route** donde colocaremos todas las reglas de enrutado que queremos crear de manera específica en nuestra aplicación web **CodeIgniter**.

Si abrimos el mencionado archivo podremos ver que ya hay dos valores de enrutado definidos en el **array $route**.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
```

Esos dos valores de enrutamiento son propios de **CodeIgniter** y están reservados para cualquier otro uso. Nosotros podemos cambiar los valores predeterminados de enrutamiento para esas variables, pero no podemos crear rutas de nuestra aplicación utilizándolos. Además estas dos rutas predeterminadas deben aparecer antes de cualquier otra ruta que definamos posteriormente en el archivo **routes.php**.

```
Nota: El primero de ellos, default_controller, sirve para definir el controlador por defecto que se ejecutaría en caso que no se indique ninguna ruta en la URL (en la raíz del dominio). En la configuración que viene en la instalación básica de CodeIgniter, si no se específica nada en la URL, se abre el controlador "welcome", pero ese controlador predeterminado lo podemos cambiar según nuestras necesidades. 
Al hablar de controladores ya se comentó qué era el controlador por defecto y cómo podemos cambiarlo. Ahora ya sabemos que ese cambio de controlador predeterminado en realidad no era más que la definición de una regla de enrutado en CodeIgniter.
```

Entonces, para crear nuestras propias reglas, se trataría simplemente de asignar nuevos valores al array asociativo **$route** y para ello tenemos que atender a la siguiente sintaxis:

**$route['de_donde_vienes'] = 'a_donde_vas';**

Como se puede ver, en las rutas tenemos dos partes:

En el índice del array asociativo, '**de_donde_vienes**', colocamos un patrón que debe coincidir para que se produzca un enrutamiento.
En el valor asignado a ese índice del array, '**a_donde_vas**', colocamos la ruta a la que estamos enviando el flujo de ejecución de **CodeIgniter**.
Ahora veamos un ejemplo de enrutamiento real:

```
$route['entradas'] = "empresa/tecnologia/5";
```

Mas ejemplos[Aqui](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/enrutado-personalizado-url-codeigniter.html)

Answer (score 0):

En tu archivo routes puedes poner lo siguiente

```
//ex.  lo_que_sea/#   => blog/id || blog/entrada/id
$route['(.+)'] = function ( $type = '' ){
                          $pos         = strpos($type, '/');

                          if( ! $pos){
                              $get_opt = substr_count($type, '/');
                              $opt     = explode('/', $type);

                              switch($get_opt){
                                  case 1://only with blog/id
                                         $return = $opt[1];
                                         break;
                                  case 2://only with blog/entrada/id
                                         $return = 'entrada/' . $opt[2];
                                         break;
                              }
                          }
                          else{
                              $return = '';
                          }

                          return 'blog/' . $retrun;
}
```

Con esto lo que haces es que con el nombre que sea y los parámetros pasados por ´/´ se formatearan en la función y se redirigirán de manera transparente al browser al controlador ´blog´ (al método ´entrada´) con el parámetro ´id´, le puedes poner un prefijo para que no te afecte con las otras paginas como por ejemplo

```
//normal page
$route['faqs'] = 'public/home/faqs';
//blog page
$route['b-(.+)'] = //codigo previo
```